# C: change into argc and argv

Tags: c, argv

I'm working on a C program with some system calls and I'm saving variables as follows:

```
int inhandle,outhandle,bytes,read_while_writing_nhandle;
char source[128],target[128];
```

Right now my program prompts the user with

```
printf("enter source file name\n"); 
scanf("%s",source);
```

**How can I change it so a user can just type "run sourceName targetName"
aka, storing them as argv[1] and argv[2]**?

I also use the inputs (target and source)
in handles like:

```
inhandle=open(source,O_RDONLY);
```

*My main issue is conversion since I'm storing target and source as char. I could use something like strcpy.*
It would just be very much appreciated if someone could help me out with it. Hope this was clear. Thank you.

*************EDIT: I apologize, I probably wasn't clear enough...

I tried doing the int main(int argc, char *argv[]) and then including:

```
if(argc==3) 
{ source = argv[1]; target = argv[2]; } 
else{ printf("Syntax error.\n"); 
return -1;
```

But I'd get conversion errors since I can't store them that way. And if I do store them as pointers (like *target=argv[2]) I'm worried they won't work when I call the handles.. (ex: outhandle=open(target...) works but I can't do open(*target..)

Comment: Huh?  If you pass in arguments on the command line, they will automatically be set in argv.

Comment: `char *source = argv[1]; char *target = argv[2];` (after checking `argc == 3` or `argc >= 3`).

Comment: The first argument to `open` has type `const char*`. So if you declare `source` to be `char*` (or `const char*`), you can just pass it directly to `open`. And, as various people have pointed out, `source = argv[1];` is a reasonable way to "save" a pointer to the first argument, since neither the `argv` array nor the strings it points to will be modified by a compliant program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
if(argc==3) 
{
    strcpy(source, argv[1]);
    strcpy(target, argv[2]);
}
```

Also, read up on the dangers of `strcpy`, and consider `strncpy`.
But using `strcpy` will get you started at least...

Answer (score 2):

Use int main(int argc, char **argv);
And then assign source to argv[1] and target to argv[2]

Comment: I tried doing that and then including: if(argc==3) {
        source = argv[1];
        target = argv[2];
        }
else{
        printf("Syntax error. Correct is 'copyit sourceFileName targetFileName'\n");
        return -1;                                                             But I'd get conversion errors since I can't store them that way. And if I do store them as pointers (like *target) I'm worried they won't work when I call the handles.. (ex: outhandle=open(target...) works but I can't do open(*target..)
        }